# Finding all java source files needed to re-create a jar

Tags: java, jar

I have a jar file (core.jar) that I need to recreate the jar from java source files using Gradle. I decompiled the jar to identify all of the class files and found the corresponding java files.

Using Gradle, I copied the java files in a directory and tried to compile them.  But the compile fails because there are more dependencies that the java files have.

I am trying to figure out how this jar was constructed.  If to compile the classes that are in a jar file needs additional java files then was the jar created by compile and project then picking a subset of the class files and packaging them up in a jar?

**UPDATE**

As per your suggestion, I checked the Manifest file and it only as this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.4
Created-By: 1.6.0_21-b06 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
```

Using JD Decompiler, there are no addition jar files in the jar that I am creating to recreate.

Comment: Check the `import` statements.

Comment: So, I have to add all of the packages defined in the import statements. But when I compile the java files, won't the jar also include all of the packages I added using the import statements?

Comment: The jar could need other jars. see the manifest inside the jar for classpath dependencies

Comment: I looked at the Manifest file and it does not have anything useful in it.  I posted it above.

Comment: Dependencies need not necessarily be declared in the manifest, depending on how the jar is being run. You should be able to tell from the compilation errors whether you actually have the sources for all classes being referenced.

Comment: OK.  Yes. I started down that road.  But when I add more files, they have dependencies and it is becoming a large set of java files to successfully compile.  I was wondering if once the compile is successful.  Will I have the same jar or one with a lot more files.  Will I have to create a task to jar only the classes that are in the original?

Comment: You can do either. If you include all dependencies in your jar, it will be self-contained. If you chose only to package the classes from the original, you will need to provide the dependencies to the classloader at runtime (by appending them to the classpath)

Comment: Will the final jar have only the classes of the original jar even though I have to add all the dependent java files to the build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to compile the files by adding the dependent classes as needed. It took some time but was able to compile the classes that I need.